# Stack Overflow format style

Tags: discussion

When I ask new question or comment, how can I add these format styles below?

[image]

Comment: "below"? You mean in comments?

Comment: Btw, we don't talk about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow itself. [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is the place where you can ask questions about SO.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that one, at least not completely. The formatting in the first rectangle is keyboard formatting, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @Stijn There is a section in the answer for formatting keyboard keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

You need is `< kbd > Alt< / kbd > + < kbd > F4 < / kbd >`

Comment: How to add background for text

Comment: Background? Like what?

Comment: The second red rectangle in my question

Comment: @KenNguyen use ( ` ) before and after of your post

Comment: Sure welcome mate. Hope it help.